# S3 PUT request from microsoft edge and IE fails because of semicolon in parameter

Tags: internet-explorer, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge

This issue might be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245389/sign-put-request-to-s3), but the platform is different so I am not sure. I had written JavaScript code in angularJS to upload an image to s3, it seems to work fine on most of the modern browsers but fails on Microsoft edge and IE 11 as far I have tested.

The code does a PUT call to update an existing s3 URI with an image file

```
let s3URLforImageUpload = encodeURI(response.payload.data) // already existing URI;
$http.put(s3URLforImageUpload, file, {headers: {'Content-Type': file.type}}) // file from ng-select directive
.success(function(response) {})
.catch(function(error) {})
```

I can see a `403` to my PUT request in the network tab.I am not sure how I can create a JSfiddle to reproduce this issue but what happens is for some reason

Chrome or Firefox treat the url and I can see in network tab for parameters like

```
X-Amz-SignedHeaders: content-type;host
```

But on Microsoft edge and IE11, I see `host` as a separate parameter

```
X-Amz-SignedHeaders: content-type
host:
```

I have tried changing the code for sending the request to `xmlhttprequest` to see if anything changes with how parameters are sent and it also gives me the same response.

```
let s3URLforImageUpload = encodeURI(response.payload.data);
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function(response) {
  console.log("RESPONSE 2", response);
}
req.open("PUT", s3URLforImageUpload);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", file.type);
req.send(file);
```

I get the same 403 response and I can see the same issue with the sent parameters. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Not going to give you a direct answer on what you've tried; but I wonder if you have given the official javascript kit [AWS Amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#put) a try.

Comment: I have not tried the AWS kit yet, A lot of s3 functionality is already in place for our web application, are you suggesting that we should switch to this tool kit and we won't have anymore issues with s3

Comment: You could refer to [this article](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/952) and try to remove the content-type. Besides, you can also check this article to [troubleshoot the error HTTP 403: Access Denied from Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/).